# Custom ECB Not Working in Personal Views

Tags: ecb-menu

I spent a lot of time creating a custom ECB in WSS. This ECB uses javascript and .Net code to give the user a lot of options on a certain list. Some of these options send the user to other pages or custom forms. Everything works fine on all the public views that were created when the site was provisioned. However, the functions that send users to custom forms stop working if the user is using a personal view of the list. The ECB displays correctly it just opens the correct page but the page is blank!! The javascript code for the ECB is in the masterpage. Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several long hours of troubleshooting, I found the cause! Yipee! It seems that in my zeal to ensure that users were returned to the page they came from, I inadvertently caused the problem. I had written the links that sent users to the pages to include a source tag in the Querystring. This was not an issue unless you were coming from a personal view! It seems that SharePoint did not like this type of URL because it contains the PageView=Personal (Or at least that was what it appears to not like!)